# Change the sequence of uicollectionviewcell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to change the sequence to cells rendered in collectionview. By default in vertical layout collectionview cells are displayed in

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

What i am trying to do is change this sequence in following ways

```
1  2  3
6  5  4      <----- this order is reversed
7  8  9
12 11 10     <----- this order is reversed
```

Can any one tell me how do i achieve this kind of behaviour.

So far i have implemented `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and trying to manipulate its methods but got no success

**Note: All items must be loaded in one section only**

Comment: you are on the right path, you have to implement a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` and that will do the job for you; you need to focus to implement a custom the `–centerForIndexPath:frame:` method for achieving the desired layout.

Comment: @holex can you please provide me an example or reference?

Comment: there are many good examples around the net about implementing custom layouts... if I were you I would start to google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by inheriting `UICollectionViewLayout` and calculated the desired frame for each item. in `prepareLayout` method.

Still there are scope for improvement in below code.

```
-(void)prepareLayout{
    NSInteger itemCount = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];
    NSMutableDictionary *layoutAttr = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    CGFloat y=0,x=0;
    for (int i = 0; i<itemCount; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
        CGRect frame;
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            x= 0;
            y=0;
            frame = CGRectMake(x,  y, self.itemSize.width, self.itemSize.height);
            x += self.itemSize.width;
        }else if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ) {
            y += self.itemSize.height;
            x -=self.itemSize.width;
            frame = CGRectMake(x,  y, self.itemSize.width, self.itemSize.height);
            if (x <= 0) {
                x += self.itemSize.width;
            }else{
                x -= self.itemSize.width;
            }
        }else{
            frame = CGRectMake(x,  y, self.itemSize.width, self.itemSize.height);
            x += self.itemSize.width;
        }
        attributes.frame=frame;

        attributes.zIndex = i;
        layoutAttr[indexPath] = attributes;
    }
    layoutAttributes=layoutAttr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this you will be required to build your own collection view layout. Start by reading the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html

Otherwise, you might be lucky and find one on http://cocoapods.org/
I made a quick search and came back with nothing.

As suggested by richarddas...

Here's a tutorial:
http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial

You should also check out the WWDC video:
http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/232xxz8gxpbstio/232/232_hd_advanced_user_interfaces_with_collection_views.mov?dl=1

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**How to implement a custom UICollectionFlowLayout**

To learn how to get started with Custom Collection View Layouts, I highly recommend this link: http://www.objc.io/issue-3/collection-view-layouts.html

Start by subclassing UICollectionViewLayout and overriding layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewDataSource *dataSource = self.collectionView.dataSource;
    id<CollectionViewDataSourceItem> item = [dataSource itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];

    // here you can customise the frame of your item if it is on a row that is even
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
    {
        CGFloat horizontalOffset = ???; // change to your new offset, positive or negative
        CGRect rect = CGRectOffset( attributes.frame, horizontalOffset, 0);
        attributes.frame = rect;
    }
    return attributes;
}
```